# How do I COALESCE different date types

Tags: mysql, date

I am trying to use `COALESCE()` to get the lowest non `NULL` date with a default to `NOW()` from the following table:

```
date1 (timestamp) | date2 (date) | date3 (timestamp)
<null>              <null>         2015-02-04 21:29:05
```

The query I have tried is:

```
SELECT coalesce(date1, timestamp(date2), date3, now()) as edited
FROM backupDB
```

Comment: convert/cast them...

Comment: I think your code should work, what's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar the issue is that I get a NULL back instead of NOW()

Comment: @JoePhillips even ```CAST``` I get ```NULL```

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47f74e/1

Comment: `COALESCE()` should never return `NULL` if one of the arguments is non-null.

Comment: Better example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/175d8d/1 (the previous example was putting a default timestamp into `date1`.

Comment: @Barmar  That is what I thought and yet I'm getting a ```NULL```

Comment: Can you reproduce at sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar - No, I cannot reproduce the error in SQLFiddle, the schema and values I truly have breaks their Java.

**Solved**

I had to dig deeper into how the table was built and find the right schema.  This is what I truly have in the DB (though PHPStorm shows "0000-00-00" as a `NULL`):

```
CREATE TABLE backupDB (
  date1 TIMESTAMP NULL,
  date2 DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  date3 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO backupDB (date1, date2, date3) VALUES
(NULL, '0000-00-00', '2015-02-04 21:29:05');
```

So the necessary query looks more like this: (feel free to criticize and improve)

```
SELECT
  coalesce(date1, if(date2= '0000-00-00', null, timestamp(date2)), date3, now()) as edited
FROM backupDB
```

Comment: So basically `COALESCE` wasn't returning `NULL`, it was returning `0000-00-00 00:00`. PHPStorm was displaying a non-null value as `NULL`. Time to file a bug report. SQLFiddle at least gives you a `Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date` error message.